# Clarification on Indian visa

Tags: visas, india, malaysian-citizens

I am Malaysia citizen. Recently I had to renew my Malaysian passport, but my Indian visa still valid up to 2015 in my old Malaysian passport. Can I carry both passport and travel through Malaysian immigration and Indian immigration.

Answer (score 5):

As per the information mentioned on [India Visa Center](http://www.indiavisa.com.my/faq.php) in Malaysia (responsible for processing Indian visa applications in Malaysia), you can travel with your old passport (and of course the new one), which has a valid Indian visa. Though, they also mentioned that you can get the visa transferred through an application.

> **Transfer of Visas:**
>
> To transfer visas from an expired passport to the new passport, visa
>   application form duly filled in along with one photo and the required
>   fees. You can also travel with expired old passport that has valid
>   Indian visa and valid new passport issued subsequent to issue of
>   Indian visa. Besides the above-mentioned categories, visas are also
>   available for learning Yoga, Music and Dance in India from the
>   institutions approved by the Government of India.

The office address along with the phone numbers for the Kuala Lumpur office are mentioned here.

> IVS VMS Sdn. Bhd.
>
> G-01, Ground Floor,
>
> Straits Trading Building, No. 2,
>   Lebuh Pasar Besar, 50050 Kuala Lumpur.
>
> Tel: 603 2692 2692 | Fax: 603 2698 2692
>
> Email:kl@indiavisa.com.my

I would strongly urge you to contact them and get clarifications from them. The information on the website might not be reflecting the latest changes in the rules or regulations. What I have heard from someone I know is, sometimes it depends on the immigration agent sitting at the desk, who will be checking your documents.